# Firebase value not being deleted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to delete one child from Firebase, however, it is not removing it for some reason.

This is how I tied to delete it(I get the right reference):

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(commentsArray[indexPath.row].key).removeValue()
```

If I try to `po` this value the output is e.g:

> https://snuspedia.firebaseio.com/posts/coments/-KTzfD1wOa9sRXw93gAF

Which is this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `print(commentsArray[indexPath.row].key)` ?

Comment: The output is e.g `-KTzfD1wOa9sRXw93gAF`

Comment: Okay, see. that is why it is not working

Comment: You don't have a child after posts, that is called `-KTzfD1wOa9sRXw93gAF`

Comment: your desired child ends with `W8k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I recognize is that you miss the key of the post:

```
https://snuspedia.firebaseio.com/posts/<KEY OF YOUR POST>/comments/-KTzfD1wOa9sRXw93gAF
```

Reference code should include the key of the specific post:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(<KEY OF YOUR POST>).child("comments").child(commentsArray[indexPath.row].key).removeValue()
```

Comment: I tried like this: `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(selectedPost.key).child(commentsArray[indexPath.row].key).removeValue()` Which not working

Comment: Output with comment was: `"https://snuspedia.firebaseio.com/posts/-KTyx4ZgsOn5JM6kqW8k/-KTzfBGN9P07WFtZ45ru"`

Comment: ok thats not what I've expected. I expected `https://snuspedia.firebaseio.com/posts/-KTyx4ZgsOn5JM6kqW8k/coments/-KTzfD1wOa9sRXw93gAF`

Comment: Wow.. what the hell.. No, I didn't copied but ye why it is with one m. Let me check.

Comment: ok can you try my updated answer? I forget the child("comments")

Comment: Yep.. i've been working too long. This little typo and didn't think clear :D

Comment: haha, yeah even me. These typos are sometimes really annoying, but it reminds me never give up and have a close look again